# Facebook Development and the Invite system

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a test Facebook app to just get a feel for the platform.

Programatically I can send invites with the FB API.
I send my friend an invite and he can accept the invite which takes him to my app. If he leaves the app, he can't get back to it because it does not show up in his Apps list. His Apps link says App Requests. (Is Facebook A/B Testing this?) Of course, he could bookmark the app but he shouldn't have to. The other thing I noticed. Is in my Facebook dev apps dashboard my User count is still 0.

Main question: He can't see a link to the app anywhere? And also me as the developer can't see a link without going into the Developer app.

Is this because the app is not listed/published yet in the directory? This is very confusing. Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is redoing the invite system. They introduced the new Requests system early in the year, and recently released v2.0. Requests under the new system will remain until you delete them programmatically or the user clicks the "X". http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

As for user count, unless you request authorization and they grant it, your user count will stay at 0.

Comment: I had 4 users accept the app (authorize it). And the User count remains at 0. Any thoughts? +1

Comment: 1. They removed the app. 2. Facebook's counts are off. I'd go with #2, which has happened to me a number of times. It generally resolves itself in time. You can get an app session token and try querying for those user's information. If you can access it, then Facebook count is just off. It has nothing to do with it not be "published".

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a bit and see what happens with the counts. app session token <-- also good to know.